# SonarQube upgrade from 4.5.7 to 5.6

Tags: sonarqube

We are trying to upgrade sonarqube from 4.5.7 to sonarqube 5.6 LTS version. During upgrade i see the error

```
2016.07.15 17:19:11 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2016.07.15 17:19:11 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/sonar]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileService
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:693) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:190) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:113) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileBackuper
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileReset
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.QProfileReset
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class com.contemplateltd.tools.sonar.profile.CceProfile
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class com.contemplateltd.tools.sonar.analysis.AnalyserContext
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67) ~[sonar-core-5.6.jar:na]
        ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/platform/PluginRepository
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$3.run(ConstructorInjector.java:403) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$3.run(ConstructorInjector.java:401) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the contemplateltd plugin (see classes com.contemplateltd.tools.sonar.profile.CceProfile and com.contemplateltd.tools.sonar.analysis.AnalyserContext in stacktraces). I don't know what's the status of this plugin regarding SonarQube 5.6 LTS. You should contact its maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same error yesterday, also trying to upgrade from 4.5.7 to 5.6, following [this procedure](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading).

In my case, it was due to an excessive copy-and-paste in `conf/sonar.properties`, where I had copied my LDAP configuration whereas the LDAP module was not installed yet.

I commented it, and the application was able to start.
Then I installed the LDAP module from the SonarQube GUI, re-enabled my LDAP configuration, and restarted the application.
It worked.

This might not be the origin of your problem, but I recommand that you check you're not trying to start any not-installed-yet module.